# VBA: Why Worksheet Change Event only firing single cells?

Tags: excel, vba

The code is working fine if a change was made for cell by cell for any of the columns, but, if I changed more than 1 cell together then the change is not reflected, anyone has any idea why?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Data!O:O")) Is Nothing Then                  
        Target.Offset(0, 14) = Now
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("Data!F:F")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsEmpty(Target.Value) = False Then
            Target.Offset(0, 21) = Target.Value
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Target.Value) = True Then
            Target.Offset(0, 21) = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("Data!H:H")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsEmpty(Target.Value) = False Then
            Target.Offset(0, 20) = Target.Value
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Target.Value) = True Then
            Target.Offset(0, 20) = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: change or select?? How do you change the value of more that one cell at once? (When you select a range only the top left cell is changed). I would also check what is the target range value debugging and share that in the question, bacause if the changed range is not in the target range, that would be the investigation starting point :)

Comment: @rustyBucketBay _How do you change the value of more that one cell at once?_ - copy/paste

Comment: `IsEmpty(Target.Value)`  doesn't work with a multi cell Target range

Comment: @chrisneilsen I've tried <> "" / = "" as well but didn't work also. I believe that GSerg has solved the issue through loop which takes both (isempty / = "") in consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little demo for column **O**.  If any cell or **group** of cells in the column change, then the date is recorded in the adjacent cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RangeOfInterest As Range, Intersection As Range, cell As Range
    
    Set RangeOfInterest = Range("O:O")
    Set Intersection = Intersect(Target, RangeOfInterest)
    
    If Intersection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In Intersection
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note we loop over all changed cells in column **O**.

**EDIT#1:**

As [GSerg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg) points out, there is no need to loop in this case:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RangeOfInterest As Range, Intersection As Range, cell As Range
    
    Set RangeOfInterest = Range("O:O")
    Set Intersection = Intersect(Target, RangeOfInterest)
    
    If Intersection Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
            Intersection.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Note we loop` - but we don't have to. `Intersection.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date`.

Comment: @Zatary  See my **EDIT#1**